# AWS - Can I use EC2 free tier instance to make use of SES free tier?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ses

[Amazon SES Free tier](https://aws.amazon.com/ses/pricing/) has 62000 free emails per month. I wonder if I create a free tier ec2 instance and use SES on that and be eligible for 62000 free emails per month? I would want to make the EC2 instance as a relay so my other non-aws instance can use the ec2 instance to send email?

Is this allowed or possible? If its possible I guess I would need to purchase a static elastic IP for my ec2 instance as well right? Since I want the ec2 to be a relay for other non-aws hosts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason why the EC2 free tier and the SES free tier can't be used together as long as you select the same AWS region for both services.  (Otherwise there would be cross-region bandwidth charges.)

Regarding using an Elastic IP (EIP), those are also free as long as they are attached to an instance, and that instance is running, and no other EIPs are attached to the same instance at the same time... and there are good reasons to use one here... but as a matter of best practice, you should prefer a DNS hostname pointing to this mail relaying machine, and configure those other systems to use DNS to find this machine, even though the address is static.  Hard-coding static IP addresses (whether in AWS or any other network) will almost always, eventually, prove to have been a mistake, and sometimes a very expensive or embarrassing one.

Comment: Keep in mind the EC2 free tier is only free for 12 months. After that you pay normal rates. This may or may not be higher than if you just used SES directly, depending on your mail volume.